# tab-expansion and “./” bash shell

Tags: bash, ubuntu, scripting, environment-variables

Maybe someone here would be able to help me out. Have installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (kubuntu) on two machines. The `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` files are identical as the file structures on each machine is the same.

**On machine 1**: I run bash scripts within a terminal window with the simple: `./scriptname.sh`

**On machine 2**: I cannot do this and must use: `sh scriptname.sh`
Nor can I use `./` and tab-complete the script filename.

All executable bits are set correctly, all files and folders have the correct permissions. In the header of the scripts the shebang is set correctly.

Any ideas why this would be occurring?

When I try `ls -l`, I get:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 adelie adelie 351 Nov 4 20:32 file_motion_grab.sh
```

Output of `getfacl` is:

```
# file: file_motion_grab.sh
# owner: adelie
# group: adelie
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::rwx
```

More general - any new script on the second machine must be invoked with: sh scriptname.sh Something probably wrong in the .bash files. But not sure where to look.

**EDIT**

Yep parent directory is all set correctly.

Comment: also asked on [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/q/212005/10127) and 
[stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13224804/7552)

Comment: are you sure you have exec permission on the _PARENT_ directory?

Comment: @guido yep - parent directory is all set correctly.

Comment: [Don't crosspost](http://unix.stackexchange.com/faq#cross-posting). Still open on AU and SO; closing here